# Check if an object exist in an array in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have an array of categories: `this.categories`

```
[ { "id": 6, "name": "categories.ladies_team" }, { "id": 2, "name": "categories.junior_team" }, { "id": 7, "name": "categories.master" }, { "id": 5, "name": "categories.ladies_single" }, { "id": 1, "name": "categories.junior" }, { "id": 3, "name": "categories.men_single" }, { "id": 4, "name": "categories.men_team" } ]
```

Now I have a new element:

```
const newCategory = {
    id: category.id,
    name: category.name
};
```

I would like to insert it if not present.

I tried:

```
if (!this.categories.includes(newCategory)) {
    this.categories.push(newCategory);
  }
```

but it is not working...

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, you need to define "not present", and then find if `some()` element of the array matches the predicate indicating that it's present

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately, `includes` will not work unless it is the same instance. You will need to do something like;

```
if (!this.categories.some((item) => item.id == newCategory.id)) {
    this.categories.push(newCategory);
}
```

Comment: some return true/false while find returns the found item in the array or undefined when item is not found. So some is really helpful just to know the existence of the item in array.

Answer (score 5):

The solution given by user184994 didn't worked for me, It was only fetching the first element. I tried like this which worked for me.

```
let data = this.categories.find(ob => ob.id === newCategory.id);
if(data === null){
 this.categories.push(newCategory);
}
```

Comment: if an element is not found then data would be undefined rather then null.

Answer (score 0):

Anindyo Bose solution also not working. Replacing null check with undefined works for me.

```
let data = this.categories.find(ob => ob.id === newCategory.id);
 if(data === undefined){
      this.categories.push(newCategory);
}
```